# LEFT JOIN with GROUP by in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am not able to get Left JOIN with the count of the secondary table. data return with LOOKup and GROUP by but order count with 0 scenarios not working, by default it treats as inner join.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "join" concepts don't really exist in Mongodb as we're talking about unstructured database by nature, Then at some point `$lookup` was added and gave us a "left join" capability, still i feel like its "wrong" to use these structured concepts when dealing with Mongo.

With that said this following pipeline should suffice your needs:

```
db.Orders.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$product_id",
            sum: {$sum : 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "product",
            local_field: "_id",
            foreign_field: "_id",
            as: "product"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$product"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Product_id: "$_id",
            OrderCount: "$sum",
            ProductName: "$product.Name"
        }

    }
])
```