# Left join with group by and having clause in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, left-join, having-clause

I have one collection named **users** and second collection named **videos**. I want to perform left join with group by and having clause. I know how to do in mysql but not getting how to get it in Mongoose.

Below are my collections[image]

in mysql query can be like

"**select u.id,u.masterid, count(v.vid) from users u left join videos v on u.id=v.uid group by u.id having u.masterid=1**"

I have found few solutions related to group by or left join [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802026/left-join-with-group-by-in-mongodb) but not with having clause. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks